# What should we call our chatroom?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

We have a [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28945/hardware-recommendations). It's currently called "Hardware Recommendations", which is the default name for a new site's chatroom.

What better names are there? As one of the [Real Essential Meta Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223674/the-real-essential-questions-of-every-beta), this is something we can tackle now.

Comment: There's a pun somewhere in here that I can't quite get to work. Something like it being "hard" to find "where" the perfect recommendations are. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): this suggestion, having won out in the voting after a fortnight, has been used as the name.

## The Rec Center

A play on "Recreation Center" that describes what happens there while still giving a nod to the site's name.

Comment: Sounds [oddly familiar](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/320/46) ;)

Comment: @Undo I swear I didn't see that. :-)

Answer (score 6):

### The Hardware Store

Cheesy and stupid. :)

Comment: this is bad since you don't want people to ask about hardware, that is not computer hardware. For me I think of nuts/bolts/screws when I think of a hardware store...

Comment: http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14/what-should-we-call-our-chatroom

Answer (score 6):

### The Benchmark

### Benchmarking Room

Usually associated with assessing/evaluating performance characteristics of computer hardware.

Comment: Yes. I like this one.

Comment: I particularly like "The Benchmark", even though it's not technically a place it rolls off the tongue easier.

Answer (score 4):

### Hardline

I was thinking that the chat room could be less about purchasing and more about a discussion. (Also kinda cheezy)

Comment: Anther thought was Hard Recs! (As it sounds like an action hero group haha.)

Comment: @Gram-I would recommend you to name it "The Computer Users"

Answer (score 2):

**The Hardware Showroom** 
(or some variation of it)

This site offers the best hardware on the market. Why not put it in a showroom?

Answer (score 0):

#### The Abacus

Since ancient times, the abacus was early used for arithmetic/computation tasks. Roman abacus was used in Babylonia as early as 2400 BC and this was early device of computing hardware based on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_computing_hardware#Early_devices).

Answer (score -1):

#### [ENIAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC)

The first electronic general-purpose computer hardware (Turing-complete device).

Answer (score -1):

### [Napier's bones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napier%27s_bones)

An 18th century manually-operated calculating device (Renaissance hardware).

Comment: Gosh, that sure sounds spooky!

Answer (score -1):

### Vacuum

Short for [vacuum tube computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vacuum_tube_computers). These are early programmable digital computers by using electromechanical relays and followed by systems built from discrete transistors.

Answer (score -3):

### The Keyboard

This is the key hardware which we all use since beginning of computer era and it will stay for further for longer period of time. I'm sure ~99% of chat users (exempt smart-device users) use it as a primary device on the chat room. Without it, you won't be able to use the chat.

Comment: Possibly, but I can't really see us having a chatroom called the Keyboard.

Answer (score -4):

If the Software Recoommendations chat is the [Rec Center](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/320) (which it isn't, and that proposal currently sits at #2), then the Hardware Recommendations chat should be the **Rec Peripheral**.

Comment: This sounds dumb to me..

Comment: @enderland https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun

Answer (score -4):

### HDD

This is the main hardware where all information is stored (unless it's SSD:), including everything what's happening on chat. We rely on it and when it fails (the one where we keep chat logs), the chat room fails.

Comment: What relation does this have to a chat room? Sure, it's hardware, but it's neither punny nor chatroom name material.

Comment: HDD is a hardware.

Comment: Well aware of that. I even said "sure, it's hardware" in that last comment. It still doesn't work as a chatroom name, for me.

Answer (score -5):

### The Store

Shorter version of *The Hardware Store*. This is the place where you talk about your hardware and you get recommendations.

Comment: No, because this doesn't tell anyone anything about what the chatroom is.

Comment: Many chat room names doesn't tell you that.

Comment: True, but they should if possible. If there are better suggestions, and the community thinks there are in this case, they should be used.

Answer (score -6):

**The Hardware General Square**